# При импорте xlsx выдает ошибку

Tags: php, xlsx

При копировании файла пере импортом выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SpreadsheetReader: File (kkasd233.xlsx) not readable' in /home/mensvint/mens-vintage.com/www/export_inport/SpreadsheetReader.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /home/mensvint/mens-vintage.com/www/export_inport/import.php(49): SpreadsheetReader->__construct('kkasd233.xlsx') #1 {main} thrown in /home/mensvint/mens-vintage.com/www/export_inport/SpreadsheetReader.php on line 44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpreadsheetReader выдает эту ошибку в случаях если он не может найти файл по тому пути что вы ему задали или если нет прав на чтение этого файла.
Убедитесь что правильно задан путь к файлу и файл доступен для чтения.